# Как из IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition сделать WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

Перепала мне лицензия на IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition, хотя я просил WebStorm для работы c JavaScript. Поставил и сразу же начинаются проблемы: то Gradle не устраивает, что стоит JRE, а не JDK, то JavaScript plugin нужен (хотя, вроде как для Ultimate должен стоять по умолчанию), то еще чего. Т.е. вместо удовлетворения от получения качественного продукта получил дополнительный геморрой. У кого есть опыт настройки, поделитесь пожалуйста, как это можно сделать безо всяких излишеств, т.е. грубо говоря, сделать WebStorm из IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Может стоит написать в поддержку Jet Brains и поменять лицензию, а не вот это вот всё?

Comment: Может, только не получится.

Comment: @vitaliy4us почему это не получится? я через техподдержку менял годовую лицензию phpStorm на intellijIdea Ultimate.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто установите необходимые плагины. Я таким образом добавил весь функционал phpStorm в IntellijIdea Ultimate.

Comment: JavaScript plugin входит по умолчанию, возможно, вы отключили какой-то плагин, от которого этот плагин зависит? Вообще можно, конечно, поотключать все ненужное ( и добавить нужное), но, может, проще все же поступить так, как вам советуют выше (т.е. поменять лицензию)?

Comment: Господа, ну я же пишу что не получится поменять. Неужели вам так важно почему? Вопрос не об этом, а о том, как вы верно изволили заметить, что нужно поотключать и что добавить? Что отключить, например, чтобы Gradle не ругался и не подчеркивал мне красным проект, а я бы потом полчаса искал, где у меня ошибка, пока бы не понял, что это ненужный мне Gradle. Что вообще отключить, что касается Java и пр., а что нужно подключить для работы с JavaScript?